# Rails 3.1 time zone confused?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Here is my current situation:

I have a user class that has an attribute time zone.

When the user creates a Lecture with start_time (3pm) and end_time (5pm), I want to ensure that in the database the start_time and end_time are actually 3pm and 5pm, in the user's time zone.

In my application controller I'm doing the following:

```
def set_timezone
  if current_user
    Time.zone = current_user.time_zone or "Eastern Time (US & Canada)"
  end
end
```

When the above lecture is saved to the database it seems to add 4 hours. Is it converting it back to UTC? The odd thing is that when I display the time in the view it is correct (I'm guessing it's converted from the UTC time back to the EST time).

I want it so that that if a user selects 4pm it is saved in the database as 4pm AND when I display that time in the view it is 4pm. What am I currently doing wrong?

EDIT: it appears that rails also converts all times to UTC when storing them in the database. Which is ok until I do a query that involves time (I'll have to manually convert it to UTC).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[MySQL also has a time zone.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time-zone-support.html)

Notably (emphasis mine):

> The current session time zone setting affects display and storage of time values that are zone-sensitive. This includes the values displayed by functions such as NOW() or CURTIME(), and values stored in and retrieved from TIMESTAMP columns. **Values for TIMESTAMP columns are converted from the current time zone to UTC for storage, and from UTC to the current time zone for retrieval.**

Whether or not it's worth doing anything about it... not sure. I'm skeptical.